# Publicação iOS, Rejeição: Guideline 2.3.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata

Tags: ios, swift, itunes

Galera, estou com essa rejeição do iTunes

> De Apple
>
> 2. 3 Performance: Accurate Metadata
> 3. 3 Design: Spam

porem pelo que entendi são os prints que adicionei, o aplicativo é só um link para o site, não tem segredo ou complexidade em cima dele. Alguém já teve essa rejeição? Podem me dar uma luz sobre ela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você mesmo disse, seu app é "só um link para o site".

De acordo com as guidelines:

> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it
>   beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful,
>   unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App
>   doesn't provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, or is just
>   plain creepy, it may not be accepted. Apps that are simply a song or
>   movie should be submitted to the iTunes store. Apps that are simply a
>   book or game guide should be submitted to the iBooks Store.

Resumindo: seu app deve conter funcionalidades, conteúdo e UI que a diferenciem de um simples website. Se seu app não for útil, ele não deve pertencer à App Store.

---

Se pergunte: qual a diferença entre o usuário baixar seu app ou manualmente criar um atalho na home screen?

Comment: Entendi, pior que ainda tentei "enganar" ele com uma splash screen, e mesmo assim ele barra o app. Publiquei o mesmo no android e deu certo, achei que a Apple também aceitaria. O jeito é orientar o usuário a adicionar o link da pagina, mas é algo que não é intuitivo para usuários comuns, por isso a sugestão de app que é mais fácil do usuário compreender. Muito obrigado, apple é uma plataforma nova pra mim.